# Количество вершин двоичного дерева

Tags: алгоритм, структуры, java, дерево

Алгоритм дерева написала. Надо написать алгоритм подсчета количество вершин, сумма поддеревьев которого меньше 500.

Comment: @Ksenia, Вы зря меняете свои вопросы так, что ответы данные для предыдущей формулировки вопроса становятся **абсолютно неадекватными**.

Переделывайте вопрос, дополняя его, а не удаляя весь предыдущий текст.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Модифицируйте ваше дерево так, чтобы в каждом узле хранилась *"сумма его поддеревьев"* (зависит от того, что вы вложили в это понятие) и *количество вершин* в поддеревьях.

> Общий смысл здесь в том, что теперь любая операция, перестраивающая дерево, также должна обновлять эти поля.
>
> То есть, если вы **добавили** узел, то нужно пробежаться от него вверх до корня и обновить количество вершин и ваши знаменитые *суммы его поддеревьев*.

- Рекурсивно обойдите дерево сверху и, если встретите узел, у которого *сумма поддеревьев* < 500, то выведите *количество вершин* на экран.